# Run both Authorize Filter and Action Filter on unauthenticated ASP.NET MVC request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, asp.net-authorization

I have decorated my base controller with a couple of action filters.  They work fine.

One of those filters sets up the request - does things like set the culture based on the domain, etc.

I also have a handful of actions that require authorization using the Authorize attribute.

My problem is that when an user attempts to request a page they are not authorized to access, the authorization filter kicks in and redirects them to a page telling them that they cannot vie the page.

The issue is that the action filters never run so the culture and other request data is never set.  This effectively causes language to be wrong in the view and other data to be missing.

I know that authorization filters run first but my question is this: How can I design this such that I can ensure that certain methods are always run before the view is returned, regardless of the authorization.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) (under the Filter Order header), Authorization filters always run before Action filters. This means that messing with `Order` properties won't help.

I think the best way to handle this is to write your own Authorization attribute (by subclassing `AuthorizeAttribute` and overriding `AuthorizeCore`) and running your action filters manually when authorization fails.

Comment: Thanks.  I later found this out and ended up doing what you recommended anyway.

Answer (score 1):

See **Order of Execution for Action Filters** on [MSDN Article on Action Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609.aspx)

Basically, you can supply an `Order` property on those culture filters so it runs *before* the Authorization filter, something like this:

```
[CultureRedirect(Order = 1)]
public class MyBaseController : Controller { }

[Authorize(Order = 2)]
public class RequiresAuth : MyBaseController { }
```

...

If that fails, you can still **[Execute code bfore an action executes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609.aspx#ExecutingCodeBeforeAndAfterFromWithinAController)** and before any ActionFilter will executes.